# Discord bot throws the error saying You are not the owner

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i have this code running and for some reason it raises the error
**Code:**

```
@command(name="sendupdate", aliases=["su"], hidden=True)
@is_owner()
async def send_bot_update(self, ctx, *, msg):
    pass
```

**Error:**

```
raise NotOwner('You do not own this bot.')
discord.ext.commands.errors.NotOwner: You do not own this bot.
```

When checked by running the following code which returns the it's info:

```
info = await self.bot.application_info()
```

The owner is me and i'm using the commad from same acc where i created the bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have specified a different owner id in the bot constructor. If not, try specifying it explicitly.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your_prefix", owner_id=your_id_here)
```

This *should* work.